# How can I center blog posts on Blogger with Contempo template?

Tags: blogger

I started using Contempo template on Blogger but I cannot center blog posts. For some reason, they are aligned on the left side but I cannot find any option to center them in settings nor I am able to change the HTML to do it. Even if I change widths, the posts won't move to the center. I am afraid this is due to some changes that I made in the past to the HTML page but I don't know how to fix this.

Here's a link to the blog and a screenshot: [www.darinworldwide.com](http://www.darinworldwide.com).

[image: xxx Screenshot xxx]

I'm not a coder and I've been suggested to ask this question here by developers on the Google Forum.

Thanks. Best,
Savi

Comment: What have you tried? For which screen resolution? should the sidebar be ignored or also be part of the centered part? Please add some more Information.

Comment: btw. when I open the link, there is a sidebar, and in your screenshot not. Is the problem solved? How can I reproduce this Error?

Answer (score 0):

Surround the text you want to center with p-tags plus text-align style definition like this:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
TEXT HERE
</p>
```

That works in my Contempo blog. You might also want to fix [SEO issues in contempo template](https://github.com/2globalnomads/blogger-contempo-template-with-seo) if you want to attract traffic from search engine.